# Android Studio 1.5 Rendering Problems: Class could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-support-library

I just installed android studio 1.5 on windows 8. I also installed latest version of API 23. I created a project and selected the blank activity. Things are fine till now.
I changed the app theme to holo.Light and it did not render.
I added the Screen shoots.[image]

[image]

Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

I did not write any code, just changed theme. How can I fix this in android studio preview. Thanks

gradle.build

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: where is your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: click light after nexus4 , choose a appcompat theme.

Comment: @tinysunlight I changed theme to appcompat, the errors gone but the three dot (...) menu also disapeared from right top side. I was following a tutorial that says change the theme to holo.Light to show overflowMenu (...).

Comment: It's just a preview.It's useless.

Comment: but there must be something to resolve this issue?